# VScode regex replace with literal $ in replace string?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I am trying to replace css variables with sass variables.

So, find things like `var(--blue500);`  and replace with `$blue500;`

But I try find `var\(--(.*)\);` and replace `$$1`, the result is `$$1`.

If I try replace `\$$1;`, the result is `\$1`.

If I don't use dollar signs as a test and set the replace to `zzzz$1` the result is `zzzzblue500`

I could do it this way and replace all `zzzz` with `$` in a separate pass, but what am I missing here?

Comment: Side note: Change `.*` to `[^)]`*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to escape the `$` replacement with `$$` and then use the substitution value of `$1`.

The resulting expression should be: `$$$1`